# insert a print on nth line after a pattern

Tags: sed

My original requirement is to insert a print at the entry of each function. Since it is very difficult, with regular expression, I find out a partial solution, for the fulfilment of the same, I need to insert printf after my function name. and I assume it should be one line after function name. so where ever my functions definitions (here the pattern is my function name) are come, a print should come on 2nd line after that function name(first line can be the curly brace. that's why I selected second line)

Answer (score 0):

`1` to print every line.

```
awk -v fn=main '$2==fn{f=1} f{s++} s==3{print "  printf(\"%i\", 10);"; s=f=0} 1' foo.txt
```

**foo.txt**

```
int main 
{
  return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
int main 
{
  printf("%i", 10);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh god, thank u, thank u very much. this is working fine. I never thought,anyone will provide such a complex questions answer. thanks once again

Comment: One problem --- i need to edit the existing file.. that is instead of showing the result in to the screen, it should replace the original file. otherwise, there is no use for the same. regards jaison